# Mudar cor do label Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

Como faço para alterar a cor do label do meu botão dependendo do valor que ele tem?

No meu formulário, no campo `status`, preciso que quando o valor estiver em "aberto", fique verde, quando "concluído" fique em azul, e quando "cancelado" em vermelho.

Fiz uma função utilizando o Thymeleaf mais ainda nao está correto.

[image: Resultado visual da função]

Obtive o resultado fazendo assim:

```
<span class="badge badge-success"
      th:text="${f.status.descricao}"
      th:classappend="${#strings.toString(f.status) == 'ABERTO' ? 'label-success' : 'badge-danger'}">
</span>
```

Dessa forma ele fica em verde quando está em status em aberto, porém os demais valores (cancelado, concluído) são aplicados pela cor vermelha, referente à classe `badge-danger`, isso porque não sei como avaliar as outras duas opções dentro da função.

Comment: Penso que este site ira te exclarecer a dúvida.... https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_colors.asp

Comment: Isso serviu como uma luva para min ermão! Muito obrigado, comecei a mexer com thymeleaf e bootstrap a pouco tempo, entao me perdi com a condição. Mais isso foi exatamente o que precisava!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode incluir um outro ternário entre parênteses após o `:` do ternário atual.

Em vez de:

```
th:classappend="${#strings.toString(f.status) == 'ABERTO' ? 'label-success' : 'badge-danger'}"
```

Ficará:

```
th:classappend="${#strings.toString(f.status) == 'ABERTO' ?
'label-success' :
(#strings.toString(f.status) == 'CONCLUIDO' ? 'label-concluido' : 'badge-danger')}"
```

> A classe `label-concluido` é apenas um exemplo. Coloque a classe que você quer que
>   se refere ao estado "CONCLUIDO".